# Calling some javascript method from a java class

Tags: java, javascript

i want to call a javascript method from a servlet... is it possible??

i have heard of something called mozila rhino but cannot understand its use, do any 1 has any idea???

Comment: have to do some server side processing... but the processing is already done using a javascript so want to implement the same script for the work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I want to call a javascript method from a servlet... is it possible??**

Yes, have a look at the [Rhino tutorial](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html). It has a few nice examples of how to embed the execution of JavaScript in a Java application.

You may also want to have a look at the example on the [Rhino article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29#Example). I'll paste it here for reference:

Below is an example of Java code running JavaScript print('Hello, world!')

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class RhinoEngine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        try {
            engine.put("name", args[0]);
            engine.eval("print('Hello ' + name + '!')");
        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot understand just going through the same... going over the head can any1 show me a working example with a javascript and the corresponding java file..

Comment: Sure you can. Look at the examples at the pages I linked to.

Comment: i am getting error on trying the example given above... do we need to setup some environment???

Comment: i dont want java6 example have to implement by java5 only..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put a `<script>`-tag onto the website, which will then be executed.

Comment: thats done on JSP's and not on servlet i want some java code to execute the same...