# can anyone give a complete example of how to call a js using java file?

Tags: java, javascript

My code is like

#### SJCL.js

```
function encrypt(data, key){
    ......
}
```

#### abcd.java

```
public String callJavascript(String data,String key)
{
    // i want to call the encrypt method here with data,key  value passing to it
}
```

any help????

using ***java5*** only

Comment: _pls help me and give me the code to do the same_ does not sound good, does it? Can you tell us what you have tried till now?

Comment: sorry for sounding "not good".. but i am looking for java to js communication from last 3 days and came across Rhino, but the code is not working for me 

i tried this
 ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
  ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
  try {
   engine.eval("print('Hello, World')");
  } catch (ScriptException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }   

even this didnt worked...

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am looking forward to call some javascript method from a java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344661/i-am-looking-forward-to-call-some-javascript-method-from-a-java-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following articles will help you:

- [Java to JavaScript Communication](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/javatojs.aspx)
- [How Java to Javascript Communication Works in Java Plug-in](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html)

**EDIT:**

**Rhino:**

I think reading the documentation will help you to implement this.

- [Rhino Documentation](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/doc.html)
- [Rhino (JavaScript engine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29)
- [Tutorial](http://sites.google.com/site/javascript4rhino/tutorials/compile-javascript-file)

**There are also some other options:**

- [JavaScript Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine)

Comment: this 1 is using applets, but u can never b sure that applet will work correctly... as mentioned in disadvantages they are slow... so cant be sure...

Comment: @varun: Are you not developing web application ?

Comment: @ Naveed - yes it will be webapplication thing is that js is already written i dont wanna rework on converting js to java and want to explore java js communication

i have worked on applet js communication before but it didnt ensured me a correct response every time and required JRE on client side

Comment: pls also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344661/i-am-looking-forward-to-call-some-javascript-method-from-a-java-class

they have described Rhino a bit but i cant understand that...

Comment: Oh. I think I did not understand your problem. Anyway there some more links.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you checked this one: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

What you are probably looking for is under the 'Invoking Script Functions and Methods' (an example to call your 'crypt()' from java)

ok, just a thought on feasibility though:
you can always pass a 'java.io.Reader' pointing your js file, to engine.eval() but if this is a web application then you're heading for disaster. You'd be better off keeping the encrypt() functionality from sjcl.js in a separate file (say encrypt.js), [including this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) into sjcl.js.

You can then read encrypt.js once and cache its contents in a static String in your java class. You can then pass this string to engine.eval() without I/O performance impact.

Comment: even this page doesnt have wat i m looking for class EvalFile { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager(); ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader(args[0])); } } Let us assume that we have the file named "test.js" with the following text: println("This is hello from test.js"); We can run the above Java as java EvalFile test.js

where to place this js file???

Comment: got it... but simple alert is also not working for me :( 


public static void javaScriptExecute(String data) throws ApplicationException{ ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager(); ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); try { engine.eval("print('Hello, World')"); } catch (ScriptException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); } }

this method doesnt show any alerts to me :(

Comment: @varun: if it doesnt print Hello, World on the console, then you have other problems. What does your stack trace say?

Comment: got the problem this feature is there in java6 not in java5 i have to use java5 only so will need something related to "Rhino" only